# Do I need transactions for read-only access in mssql/readcommited environment

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, transactions

Assuming, we are using MSSQL and working on read commited isolation level (so, the associated phenomena are acceptable) do I need a transaction when performing several consecutive select queries? Is there any difference between performng several consecutive select queries in a single transaction and performing them in separate transactions?

Comment: Why do you think you might need a transaction? Are you wanting to enforce some consistency between the `select` statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no difference whatsoever. Under default `read committed` isolation level `S` locks are released as soon as data is read.

It doesn't wait until the end of the statement even let alone the end of the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any difference between performng several consecutive select queries in a single 
>   transaction and performing them in separate transactions?

Depends on the isolation level of the selecting connnection. Can be a lot (leaving locks on every item read) or not.